# Function reads the last xml file instead of full list

Tags: r, xml

Could anybody help me woth below occasion?

Instead of reading all the files from folder, function returns value only from the last file from a list.

```
function1<-function(directory){
  setwd("D:/folder")
  filelist<-list.files(pattern = "*.xml")
  for (i in 1:length(filelist)){
    doc <- xmlTreeParse(filelist[i], useInternal = TRUE)
    rootNode<-xmlRoot(doc)
    c4<-xpathSApply(rootNode,"//Table//node", xmlValue)
    return(node)
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: As soon as `return(node)` is reached the loop is interrupted, so only `i = 0` will be evaluated...depending on your needs, you could add the node to a list and return it at the end of the method

Comment: But function returned the value from the last file in the list, not i=0. Or it's the same? Could you please edit my code to fix it?

Comment: are you 100% sure about that? we don't know that b/c you haven't provided a reproducible example nor any indication of what's in `filelist`, the contents of `filelist[1]` or the contents of `filelist[length(filelist)`. You should also be using `for (i in seq_along(filelist))` or even `for (xfile in filelist)` and using `xfile` instead of `filelist[i]`.

Comment: It returns the same result. I tried to process it from the folder several times with variable count of files and function always returns value only from the last file.

Comment: `node` variable returned by the function is not initialized in the function, so maybe, if you haven't cleared your environment, it still has the value of some old test you've done before...please explain what you want to return in your function: e.g. the list/vector of c4 values found ?

Comment: I'so sorry, it should return(c4). Actually, I try to write code to replace values in xml files, but firstly I tried to return value c4. Initial code is below:

Comment: function1<-function(directory){
  setwd("D:/folder")
  filelist<-list.files(pattern = "*.xml")
  for (i in 1:length(filelist)){
    doc <- xmlTreeParse(filelist[i], useInternal = TRUE)
    rootNode<-xmlRoot(doc)
    c4<-xpathSApply(rootNode,"//Table//c4", xmlValue)
    c6<-xpathSApply(rootNode,"//Table//c6", xmlValue)

Comment: c13<-xpathSApply(rootNode,"//c13", xmlValue)
    lapply(xpathApply(doc,"//Table//c4"), function(n) { if (as.numeric(c13)==0)
      xmlValue(n) <- replace(c6, xmlValue(n),c4)
 })lapply(xpathApply(doc,"//Table//c6"), function(n) { if (as.numeric(c13)==0)
 xmlValue(n) <- replace(c4, xmlValue(n),c6)
})}}

Answer (score 0):

Solution is found, FYI:

```
setwd("D:/folder")
xmlfiles <- list.files(pattern = "*.xml")
sapply(seq(xmlfiles), function(i){
doc <- xmlTreeParse(xmlfiles[i], useInternal = TRUE)
c4<-xmlValue(doc[["//folder//c4"]]) 
return(c4)
})
```